# Trouble getting dates to appear on x-axis of d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I'm new to using the d3 framework, and I've been messing around with some examples from http://bl.ocks.org/. I have a working jsFiddle with a small sample of my data, but I cannot seems to get any dates to appear on the x-axis.

Can any of you see what I am missing? Much appreciated!

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ce9vkt2m/

javascript:

```
var data = [
       {'date': '130576320000000000', 'count': 3 },
       {'date': '130567680000000000', 'count': 14 },
       {'date': '130565952000000000', 'count': 1 },
       {'date': '130565088000000000', 'count': 9 },
       {'date': '130564224000000000', 'count': 17 },
       {'date': '130560768000000000', 'count': 13 },
       {'date': '130553856000000000', 'count': 55 },
       {'date': '130552992000000000', 'count': 8 },
       {'date': '130552128000000000', 'count': 238 },
       {'date': '130547808000000000', 'count': 14 },
       {'date': '130541760000000000', 'count': 20 },
       {'date': '130540896000000000', 'count': 6 },
       {'date': '130536576000000000', 'count': 38 },
       {'date': '130529664000000000', 'count': 44 },
       {'date': '130528800000000000', 'count': 43 },
       {'date': '130527936000000000', 'count': 3 },
       {'date': '130525344000000000', 'count': 20 },
       {'date': '130523616000000000', 'count': 4 },
       {'date': '130519296000000000', 'count': 20 },
       {'date': '130518432000000000', 'count': 3 },
];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%y").parse;

for(var i = 0; i < data; i++)
{
    data[i].date = parseDate(data[i].date);
    data[i].count = +data[i].count;
}

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.count; }));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".2em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

css:

```
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your date values are valid?

Comment: Well, if I change the date format to "2014-10-15", and change the d3 time format parse to "d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;" there is an error written to the console that there was an invalid value (NaN) fed to a path element. Unfortunately, that doesn't really tell me where the script is going wrong.

Comment: Your date values don't look valid to me either.  In the for loop, you're loop until i < data.... you mean i < data.length I'd say.  Then your date values get converted to NaN.  Fix your date formatting and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeh, that seems to have done it. Thanks. If you want to add your comment as an answer I can mark it as such!